# How to add non-ASCII characters to figure title in matlab headless mode?

Tags: matlab

I run matlab in batch mode on server, which doesn't have graphics. I generate plots and save them to file as follows:

```
h = figure;
hold on;
% plotting code
title('some non-ascii title', 'FontName', 'liberation serif');
print(h, 'result', '-depsc');
```

but it gives me gibberish instead of proper title.

In graphical mode, the same code outputs expected image.

I am using Matlab version 7.6, 2008a. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @EitanT - I really don't need latex. I need a simple image (be it .eps or .png, no matter). I tried to use exportfig, it gives me some warning about OpenGL (` OpenGL mode can not be used in terminal emulation mode; ignoring option.`), and outputs image at 180x150 resolution, which is way to small even to read the title. '-m2' doesn't affect the size of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You have full access to all Tex characters  `text(1,1,''\delta \pi'')` prints a delta and a pi at point 1,1.

On a server without a graphics card its best to never even render the image. Eg  `set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','off')` on your session save the figures as matlab structs using `handle2struct` or the disk version `hgsave('filename.mat')`. Then render the figures on a server with a gpu using `struct2handle` or the disk version `hgload`.

[Good Documentation on adding TEX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-annotations-to-graphs.html#f0-28104),
[Undocumented handle2struct](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format/)